# How much blood makes a niddah?

Tags: halacha, medicine, niddah

Sometimes a woman is bleeding but is not having a clear period. What amount of blood (on colored clothing) would no longer be considered a kesem but would make the woman a nidah through a presumed Reiyah?

Comment: Since when does amount matter?

Comment: The three sentences presented here constitute three completely separate questions on their own. Either this is too broad or it needs more effort to clarify what in particular is being sought. Already two answers have taken it two different ways

Comment: @DoubleAA That should be fixed now.

Comment: If a woman is bleeding but doesn't have a clear period? That's a very technical and specific situation that does not have to do with colored clothing. Such a case needs to be brought to a Rav. Your previous version was actually better. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "a presumed Reiyah"? Do you mean a Hargasha? Something else? That Hebrew term doesn't necessarily have a technical meaning, at least not a uniformly used one, so it's important to understand how you are using it.

Answer (score 6):

Any small amount of uterine blood at all that leaves the uterus is enough. There is no minimum. (See Gemara Niddah 40a; Yoreh Deah 183:1, with Shach:3)

"...even if she only saw a drop of blood the size of a mustard seed; she must observe seven clean days for it."

On the one hand, there is no amount mentioned by Chazal, that limits the exception on colored clothing. Any amount is merely a "kesem" (Rabbinical "stain" subject to those laws)

On the other hand, some factors that would need the guidance of a Rabbi to see if a "large amount" of blood found upon colored clothing renders her a niddah or at least creates a doubt:

a) It was an amount that equaled the usual stains she experiences during an onset of a menstrual flow.

b) It happened at the time of her usual monthly period.

c) There is no way the blood can be attributed to something else.

d) She had a "Hargashah" or definite feeling of a flow from the uterus, or opening of the uterus.

Comment: Sources for your claims would improve the value of your answer.

Comment: Even gallons of uterine blood doesn't matter if there's no hargasha. This answer is wrong. Your source just says any amount with hargasha is Tamei. (Also how can you justify leaving out the three things the Gemara explicitly says mask Hargasha?)

Comment: @DoubleAA The OP asked about the amount of blood that would minimally constitute "Reyiah"? The OP does not ask about other laws of niddah like hargashah. The OP also has no question regarding masking hargashah. The 2nd q asked if there is an amount of blood that ruins the heter of colored clothing. The basic answer is no. This is not a hilchos niddah shiur.

Comment: (Note the rule that question edits can't invalidate answers doesn't apply to edits made to reopen a question since such a prohibition could essentially force a question to never be openable. You need to edit this post to address the current version of the question if you don't want it to be removed/trimmed when/if the q is reopened.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks, i didn't know that. i will try to be aware if it is reopened and edit according to the new question.